# Why are the accounts of some users inaccessible?

Tags: discussion, deleted-accounts, users

For example, check this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332763/associativity-of-symmetric-difference-of-sets), the account of the OP is not clickable, and appears greyed-out:

[image: unclickable account]

Why this is the case for some accounts? Are they deleted? If yes, how can one delete their own account? Or can only the admins delete accounts? And for what reasons can accounts be deleted?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, the account in question has been deleted. (In general, accounts which are greyed out either belong to a now-deleted account, or, in the case of migrated questions, possibly to an account that was never created. When an account is deleted, the display name is reverted to the default `user####` form.)

[Voluntary account deletions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) can happen in basically two ways:

- Users with *very* low activity can delete their own accounts from their profiles.
- Requests for account deletion can be made via the [contact us](https://math.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of every page.

Of course, from time-to-time moderators discover accounts that have been created with nefarious motives (frequently sock-puppetry or suspension circumvention). When such accounts are discovered, they are usually unceremoniously deleted by the mods. Accounts created with the purpose of posting spam and other nonsense are simply *destroyed* by moderators when found, which has further implications.